Internal error in the expression evaluator.... yet again
I started with a new firm some months back and I installed VS2022 on it. On the project I was assigned to, any attempts to see values of variables failed. Adding a watch produced the error in this question's title:
Internal error in the expression evaluator. I tried every "solution" I could find and could never resolve the problem. Some kind of DLL conflict seemed like a possibility, but pulling the project fresh from TFS and rebuilding didn't cure the problem. My co-workers aren't having issues with this. I created a C# app as a test. The default applications would run just fine and I could inspect variables. More to indicate that it's something in the project.
But...
A few days ago IT gave me a new computer. Great! I could start fresh. I put a new copy of VS2022 on a virgin computer. You'd think this would fix the problem. No. It got worse. Not only would running a fresh copy of the project would not show variables, default test applications created in VS2022 wouldn't let me inspect variables either.
To my mind, the only thing that could account for this is that VS2022's installer dropped something on my computer that it didn't on anyone else's. But I'm at my wits end. If you can google a solution to this problem, I am pretty sure I've already tried it. Resetting things doesn't get more reset than new computer, new O/S and new VS2022 environment.
Has anyone got answers to this problem that Google can't find and stack-overflow hasn't supplied?
Edit:
I was told this is a duplicate question. It's not. The alleged duplicate has the following answers (summarized):

Use Managed Compatibility Mode (top two answers plus one other) - This isn't an option on VS2022.

Remove visualizers - has no effect. Also, reminder: new computer, fresh O/S, new VS2022 install.

Reset to default settings - Again, new computer, new VS2022 install. Nothing to reset to default.

Make sure you're in debug mode. - Yes, I'm in debug mode. That's pretty much the point, isn't it?

A couple other negatively voted special cases. - Obscure and don't apply.


Let me throw in steps to apply:
1 - Get a new computer with Windows 10
2 - Install VS2017 Professional.
3 - Install VS2022 Professional.
4 - Menu->File->New->Project and create a new ASP.Net Core Web API application.
5 - Run the vanilla application and breakpoint on the request for the weath4er and request it.
Finally, examine variables. It'll work for you just fine. It's not working for me at all. VS2017 works just fine.

This question contains no information except the error, Internal error in the expression evaluator. The fact this occurs in separate computers means the problem is specific to the project or the watch expression used, not Visual Studio or the OS. Without any other information one can only point to the duplicate questions

It would be good if you read what I said. I created a stock application, specifically the "weather report" API (but it doesn't matter which one) and variables couldn't be inspected. This on a new computer with a fresh install. I have no idea what other information could possibly be supplied short of mailing my computer to someone.
